# What the rules for the 'trivial answer converted to comment'

Tags: discussion, trivial

So how does SO decide when an answer is a "trivial answer" that should be converted to a comment?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment - the feature has existed since at least July 2011. Nothing new about it.

Comment: it hit me twice today - I had never seen it before

Comment: @pm100 Do you have links to the 2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783149/how-do-i-properly-reference-the-gnu-readline-library-to-scan-terminal-input

Comment: @pm100 If you are solely posting links to other SO questions, those aren't answers and you shouldn't be attempting to post it as such.  If you think that link answers the question, then vote to close as a duplicate.  If it is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240942/gcc-compilation-error-gnu-readline-library#comment44843149_28240942) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240942/gcc-compilation-error-gnu-readline-library#comment44843177_28240942) - the first isn't answer (it's just a link) and the 2nd is barely an answer.

Comment: my second one said what to do and then added the link as a reference - its still got converted to a comment

Comment: @pm100 It should have been a VTC as a duplicate, not an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Usually when it looks like this.

[Answer appears automatically converted as a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment)

Did that solve your question?

Comment: mod > convert to com... oh, wait. I see what you did there.

Comment: Seems to me that the "answer" should become a vote for a duplicate rather than a comment.